# Limit of a polynomic-exponential sequence

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

I have to calculate the following limit:
$$L=\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} -(n-n^{n/(1+n)})$$
I get the indeterminate form $\infty - \infty$ and I don't know how to follow.  Any idea?
Thank you very much.

Comment: It seems easy but...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
n-n^{n/(1+n)} = n(1- e^{-1/(1+n) \log n})\sim
n\times 1/(1+n) \log n \to\infty
$$because when $u\to 0$,

$$
e^u-1\sim u
$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT : 
$$n - n^{n/1+n} = n - n^{1+1/n} = n(1 - n^{1/n}) = \frac{1 - n^{1/n}}{1/n}$$

Now use L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Downvote, seems to me this is mostly copied from the first post that was posted.  Also, please use proper LaTex syntax to make answers more readable for the community.

Comment: @Integrals That would be hard seeing as this answer was posted first.

Comment: @AlexBecker show me proof please thanks

Comment: @Integrals If you hover your mouse over the times listed with the answer (e.g. "answered X hours ago") you get a timestamp from when the answer was posted.

Comment: @alex who are you, did you just message me? however I am not sure I know who you are.  That is helpful about the time stamp though THanks!.

Comment: @Integrals I'm one of the moderators for this site. Yes, I have contacted you through the moderator messaging system, which allows moderators to communicate with users privately about moderation issues.

Comment: @AlexBecker oh OK.  I got you rmessage and replied to it too.  I guess message me back if you  want to talk more since its private, and this isn't.  OK  THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Since you received good answers, if I may, I suggest you plot on the same graph the two following functions  $$f(n)= -(n-n^{n/(1+n)})$$ $$g(n)=-\log(n)$$ You will probably be amazed to see how close they are (even for $n$ around $100$).

In fact, but this is off topic, what you could show is that, for large values of $n$,$$f(n) \simeq \log \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+\frac{\left(\log \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-2\right)
   \log \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{2 n}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\right)$$